# Virtual DOM implementation which can parse HTML documents

Tags: javascript, go, pandoc

## Problem

I really like the concept of a Virtual DOM, described in https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html, as the amount of data between server and client can be reduced in my case. Also a diff update could be highlighted using css to show the user what has been changed.

I'd like to extend my editor https://github.com/nixcloud/pankat with incremental document updates.

My problem is this, how to get HTML into the virtual dom. Usually this is composed by functions of some sorts and not already existing documents.

Is there a:

```
vdom->parseHTML('index.html')
```

Which I missed? I guess I can run the javascript part in https://github.com/nixcloud/pankat

### Server to client updates

1. static html generator using pandoc ->
2. DOM-server-side: parse output on the server side ->
3. create a patch ->
4. update client web UI.

### Client to server updates

A user

1. edits a README.md
2. for example using the https://github.com/Jeffail/leaps editor.
3. Each update triggers the static html generator (using pandoc).
4. If a change is detected, trigger the update to the client as described above.

## update

I've been looking at my notes and I discoverd this:

http://fiduswriter.github.io/diffDOM/